# Blue prism Queues: set collection data onto one queue row

Tags: queue, blueprism

I'm out of ideas how to set a collection of multiple rows onto one queue row in Blue Prism. Set data works only with one-row collection.
Did anyone used or would have suggestions how to approach this? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One item in queue is one line from collection. If you'd like to store a multi row collection in work queue item, then you need to insert it as one field in the main collection.

[image: Image reference]

Comment: Hi, thanks for the idea! I've researched BP but could find a function to insert a collection into another collections field. What did you use? Thanks!

Comment: I defined a collection field by myself here.

Alternative approach could be to use action "Merge Collection" from "Collection manipulation" VBO. As input you could use second collection with 1 defined field of type collection.

Comment: @user78998 you can use an empty page that takes a collection as input and a collection as output (start: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Urfsd.png end: https://i.stack.imgur.com/uQKjR.png) When you refer to the page, you input the collection, on the output, you use the field which will contain the collection. E.g. input: `[Small Collection]`, output: `[Big Collection.Inside Collection]`.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a collection called "Data" that you want to package in a collection called "Queue", define a field in "Queue" as a collection (call it "Info"), then you'd just need a calculate stage to set it, which would look like this:

[Example Calculate Stage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lo8zu.png)

Comment: Thank you so much! Going to try what works best. Thanks again!